# how does magento check if a configure/grouped product is out of stock in the catalog/search

Tags: magento-enterprise, catalog, catalogsearch, stock, product-type

in the setup of magento i have i have set backorders to be on but i only needed them on so that out of stock items could be added to the cart from an order editor

i've been making changes to magento so that insted of checking if a product is in stock or not it's checking if the qty if 0 as that is a clear sign that a product is out of stock in my setup

in `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product` i have changed `isSalable` to `false` and while every item that i go into says it's out of stock, they still show up in the catalog and when i do a search

so how does magento check if a configure/grouped product is out of stock in the catalog/search cause it's obviously not from using `isSalable`

Comment: Are you using flat catalog?

Comment: @dedmeet i dont know, how do i check

Comment: System-configuration-catalog there will be settings to enable flat catalog. If enabled you need to reindex for any product changes to become active in front-end. Possible this is why you are not getting the changes.

Comment: @dedmeet the option "Use Flat Catalog Product" is set to no

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, until 1.7.0.2 magento doesn't change the inventory status of a configurable product. I think it is the same with the grouped product. I thought that was fixed on the bugathon2013 but I can't find a pull request with this issue.

https://github.com/magento/bugathon_march_2013

If in the inventory settings `Manage Stock` is `No` it is always available. If it is `Yes` it depends on `Stock Availability`.